# jquery multiple lightboxes

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm using 1 lightbox per section. Each section is an expandable DIV (in jquery). It all works fine but wondering if there's an easier way to code in jquery instead of copying the same code and changing the DIV id numbers...

here's my html:

```
<div class="bus-location">
<h5 class="accordion" id="section1">Title 2span></span></h5>
<div class="content">
<p>Content here</p>

<div class="bus-promo"><a id="show-panel" href="#"></a></div><!-- end of .bus-location-promo -->
<div id="lightbox-panel">
<h6>Heading</h6>
<p>Text goes here</p>
<p>image below</p>
<img src="../images/logo.png" />
<p align="center"><a id="close-panel" href="#">Close this window</a></p>
</div><!-- /lightbox-panel -->
<div id="lightbox"> </div><!-- /lightbox -->
</div><!-- end of .content -->
</div><!-- end of .bus-location-->

<div class="bus-location">
<h5 class="accordion" id="section2">Title 2<span></span></h5>
<div class="content">
<p>Content for div 2 here</p> 
<div class="bus-promo"><a id="show-panel-2" href="#"></a></div><!-- end of .bus-location-promo -->
<div id="lightbox-panel-2">
<h6>Promotion 2</h6>
<p>Text goes here</p>
<p>image below</p>
<img src="../images/logo.png" />
<p align="center"><a id="close-panel-2" href="#">Close this window</a></p>
</div><!-- /lightbox-panel -->
<div id="lightbox-2"> </div><!-- /lightbox -->
</div><!-- end of .content -->
</div><!-- end of .bus-location-->
```

Here's my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#show-panel").click(function(){
        $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeIn(300);
    })
    $("a#close-panel, #lightbox").click(function(){
        $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);
    })

    $("a#show-panel-2").click(function(){
        $("#lightbox-2, #lightbox-panel-2").fadeIn(300);
    })
    $("a#close-panel-2, #lightbox-2").click(function(){
        $("#lightbox-2, #lightbox-panel-2").fadeOut(300);
    })

    $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { 
      if (e.which == 27) {
        $("#lightbox, #lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);
        $("#lightbox-2, #lightbox-panel-2").fadeOut(300);
      }
    });
})
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#lightbox, #lightbox-2 {
    display:none;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90);
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
}
#lightbox-panel, #lightbox-panel-2 {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-400px;
    width:800px;
    background:#FFF;
    padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    z-index:1001;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need some good class targeting. With this you can create lightboxes ad infinitum without needing to change your code or add IDs.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3CAhb/

Here's the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.show-panel").click(function(){
        $(this).closest(".content").find(".lightbox, .lightbox-panel").fadeIn(300);
    })
    $("a.close-panel, .lightbox").click(function(){
        $(this).closest(".content").find(".lightbox, .lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);
    })

    $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { 
      if (e.which == 27) {
        $(".lightbox, .lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);
      }
    });
})
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="bus-location">
    <h5 class="accordion">Title 2<span></span></h5>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Content for div 2 here</p>
        <div class="bus-promo">
            <a class="show-panel" href="#"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="lightbox-panel">
            <h6>Promotion 2</h6>
            <p>Text goes here</p>
            <p>image below</p>
            <img src="../images/logo.png"/>
            <p align="center"><a class="close-panel" href="#">Close this window</a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="lightbox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way - capture the information you need from the click. Here is your code:

```
$("a#show-panel-2").click(function(){
    $("#lightbox-2, #lightbox-panel-2").fadeIn(300);
});
```

Here is what I would do

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var array_id = $(this).attr('id').split('-'); // separates the id into parts
    var number_from_id = array_id[array_id.length - 1]; // gets last element of the array
    $('#lightbox-' + number_from_array, '#lightbox-panel-' + number_from_array).fadeIn(300);
    // and so on
```

});

It takes a little re-organization but will prevent you from having to type code blocks over and over again.